# building TINKER package using gfortran compiler

Tags: macos, debugging, fortran

I want to be able to step through the TINKER molecular modeling package on Mac OSX 10.6.8. It can be found at http://dasher.wustl.edu/ffe/ with documentation on how to build the package using gfortran (the fortran compiler I am using). The instructions are all in the guide.txt file (provided in the TINKER Complete Distribution (GNU gzip, 18.1 Mb)) but my competency level is low so I may be missing something.

TINKER compiles a bunch of separate packages. I'd like to compile and debug the multi-file 'analyze' program, but I have little to no experience compiling fortran or using .make files.

With single line programs, it's trivial to do

```
gfortran -g myprogram.f -o myprogram
gdb myprogram
break main
run
```

or something like that. I was wondering if anybody out here can have a look at the source code build instructions and tell me the procedure for compiling+debugging the analyze.f file on its own (is the make file still necessary?)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use the Makefile from the directory 'make'.  Just copy the file to the 'source' directory and slightly adjust it.  There are settings for many different compilers at the beginning of the Makefile and you just have to check that only the gfortran settings are not commented (with #).

Basically you need to uncomment the following block

```
F77 = /usr/bin/gfortran
LIBS =
F77FLAGS = -c
OPTFLAGS = -O
LIBFLAGS = -crusv
LINKFLAGS =
```

and comment all others (in my case the Intel Fortran compiler, ifort, was the default).

And at the very beginning of the Makefile you should also insert the correct paths for the source code and installation:

```
TINKERDIR = /Users/ponder/tinker
BINDIR = $(TINKERDIR)/bin
LINKDIR = /usr/local/bin
```

Once you have the adjusted Makefile in the source directory, you just need to type

```
make all
```

to compile the whole package, and

```
make rename
```

to install the binaries in the BINDIR directory.